# How to have img popout when containing div is clicked (Image gallery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a simple image gallery and have the general structure done, at this point I'm just trying to get the Jquery to work, so when the Div is clicked on, the img inside is enlarged to full and centered on screen (like most image galleries).

Here's my HTML using bootstrap.

```
<div class = "row gallery">
    <div class = "col-md-12 gallery_row">
        <div class = "pic_div"><img src="test.png" class = "pic"></div>
        <div class = "pic_div"><img src="test.png" class = "pic"></div>
        <div class = "pic_div"><img src="test.png"  class = "pic"></div>
        <div class = "pic_div"><img src="test.png"   class = "pic"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far when I tried using Jquery I've been able to resize the image on click, but it only resizes to fit the div, rather than resize to initial size.

```
var $pic_div = $('.pic_div');

$pic_div.on('click',function(){

    $(this).find('img').css({'height' : '100%' , 'width' : '100%'});

});
```

I'm not sure how to get the image to pop out of the div, or would I have to just load the same image. I'm trying to make it easy to add new pictures so I'm straying away from specific naming for each image.

Also here is the CSS for the containing div:

```
.pic_div{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin: 25px;
overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;
```

}

Comment: Do you want image appears in a popup like with fancybox plugin or be larger when you click on it on the screen ?

Comment: I'd rather have it popup like the fancybox plugin, although this is my first time with this stuff so I'm trying to do it myself rather than use plugins.

Comment: jsfiddle maybe or any other

Comment: the reason it will only fill the div is because when you set the img inside the div 100% refers to the container.  So when you do 100% you get whatever the parent element's size is.  To make a img pop outside of the div I would use a plugin like http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=Window

Comment: https://jsbin.com/nudejeq/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I think your looking for the `transform: scale()` CSS3 property. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also roll your own lightbox:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/kwf4qsau/)</kbd>

```js
var pd = $('.pic_div');

pd.on('click',function(){
    var i = $(this).find('img').clone();
    $('#lightbox').html(i);
    $('#lightbox img').css({'width':'100%','height':'auto'});
    $('#overlay, #lightbox').fadeIn();
});
$('#overlay').click(function(){
    $('#lightbox, #overlay').fadeOut();
    $('#lightbox').html();
});
```

```css
.pic_div{width: 150px;height: 150px;margin: 25px;overflow:hidden;display:inline-block;}
#lightbox{
   position:absolute;
   top:10%;
   left:20%;
   width:60%;
   height:70%;
   z-index:2;
   display:none;
}
#overlay{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background:black;opacity:0.7;z-index:1;display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "row gallery">
    <div class = "col-md-12 gallery_row">
        <div class = "pic_div"><img src="http://placeimg.com/50/50/animals" class = "pic"></div>
        <div class = "pic_div"><img src="http://placeimg.com/50/50/animals" class = "pic"></div>
        <div class = "pic_div"><img src="http://placeimg.com/50/50/animals"  class = "pic"></div>
        <div class = "pic_div"><img src="http://placeimg.com/50/50/animals"   class = "pic"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="lightbox"></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: After playing around with it, it works great, but it doesn't seem to center the image in screen. Since the images might be different widths/heights is there a way to ensure the lightbox always centers in page. I tried margin: auto; but had no luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can take out the class attribute from the div component and put in the image component, just like this:

```
<div class = "row gallery">
    <div class = "col-md-12 gallery_row">
        <div><img class = "pic_div" src="test.png" class = "pic"></div>
        <div><img class = "pic_div" src="test.png" class = "pic"></div>
        <div><img class = "pic_div" src="test.png"  class = "pic"></div>
        <div><img class = "pic_div" src="test.png"   class = "pic"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That should do the job!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic concept. CSS uses what is commonly known as the box method (containers in containers). By default the width and height of a box or container cannot be greater than the width and height of its parent container (because the box won't fit).

To circumvent this you can change the the position of the containing div to absolute i.e it is positioned relative to the browser window  instead of being relative to its parent container.

Also rather than inserting inline styles with jQuery rather toggle the a class set for a large image, this can be animated and spruced up with css3 transitions.

Heres an example...

```js
var $pic_div = $('.pic_div');

$pic_div.on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.pic_div img {
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
.pic_div.active img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.pic_div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}
.pic_div.active {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row gallery">
  <div class="col-md-12 gallery_row">
    <div class="pic_div">
      <img src="http://www.activedemo.co.za/OA/Images_Product/BIN373502(12).jpg" class="pic">
    </div>
    <div class="pic_div">
      <img src="http://www.activedemo.co.za/OA/Images_Product/RAK05_amended(3).jpg" class="pic">
    </div>
    <div class="pic_div">
      <img src="http://www.activedemo.co.za/OA/Images_Product/OA066(2).jpg" class="pic">
    </div>
    <div class="pic_div">
      <img src="http://www.activedemo.co.za/OA/Images_Product/SF4310(7).jpg" class="pic">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```